# Dynamic column in Oracle SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

```
T_ORDER_PLACEMENTS (ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE)
T_ORDER_DETAILS (ORDER_ID, STOCK_ID)
T_STOCK_DETAILS(STOCK_ID, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_PRICE)
```

Can someone please help me to write a query which generates the following output:

```
STOCK_ID, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_PRICE, ORDERED_STATUS
1         stock1      5000         ordered
2         stock2      10000        unordered
```

Populate the `ORDERED_STATUS` column with 'ordered' if the stock is ordered and 'unordered' if the stock is unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t_stock_details.*,
    CASE WHEN order_check.stock_id IS NULL THEN 'unordered' ELSE 'ordered' END  AS ordered_status
FROM
    t_stock_details
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT stock_id FROM t_order_details GROUP BY stock_id
)
    order_check
        ON order_check.stock_id = t_stock_details.stock_id
```

The sub-query checks to see which `stock_id`s have an order associated with them.  It also uses `GROUP BY` to ensure only one row is returned per `stock_id`, no matter how many orders are found.

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that every row in `t_stock_details` is returned, whether or not it is successfully joined to anything.  Where there is a successful join, we know there has been an order.  It will also only ever be joined on to one row at the most *(thanks to the above mentioned `GROUP BY`, so no duplication is being caused)*.

An unsuccessful join will have `NULL` in the `order_check.stock_id`, so we use that to check which string to return, using a `CASE` statement.